# Firefox not affected by gtk theme

Tags: gnome, firefox, themes, gtk

How can I make firefox use Adwaita theme like all other apps do?

**Good:**
[image: good]

**Bad:**
[image: bad]

Preferably also make web pages darker as well.

Comment: You also want "Preferably also make web pages darker as well". I'm not sure that this is the job of gtk themes. For that, it's better to install [the Stylish extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/) and a suitable user style from userstyles.org (or modify userContent.css).

Comment: I had the same issue with Firefox and other GTK2 apps, and solved it using [this](http://cbowman57.deviantart.com/art/Adwaita-Dark-3-14-rev-2-492714039) theme (note a version to match the shell is needed)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use Gnome Tweak Tool to use the dark theme for all the applications:

[image: tweak tool - enable dark theme for all applications]

### BUT

Firefox uses GTK2. Gnome Tweak Tool only edits the GTK3 settings, hence we need to edit the `/usr/share/themes/Adwaita/gtk-2.0/gtkrc` file.

1. Initially we backup our gtkrc file

   ```
   sudo cp /usr/share/themes/Adwaita/gtk-2.0/gtkrc /usr/share/themes/Adwaita/gtk-2.0/gtkrc.bak
   ```
2. Next copy the following and replace your existing gtkrc file:

   ```css
   #Color scheme originally contributed by Franco Gotusso as Clearlooks-DarkOrange 
   # Based on Clearlooks-DarkCoffee by Chibi and edited by bvc as Clearlooks-DarkCoffee2

   style "clearlooks-default"
   {
     GtkMenuItem::selected_shadow_type = none
     GtkWidget::interior_focus = 1
     GtkButton::default_border = { 3, 3, 3, 3 }
     GtkButton::default_outside_border = { 3, 3, 3, 3 }
     GtkRange::trough_border = 2

     GtkWidget::focus_padding = 1

     GtkPaned::handle_size = 6

     GtkRange::slider_width = 15
     GtkRange::stepper_size = 15
     GtkScrollbar::min_slider_length = 30
     GtkCheckButton::indicator_size = 12
     GtkMenuBar::internal-padding = 0

     GtkTreeView::expander_size = 14
     GtkExpander::expander_size = 16

     GtkTreeView::odd_row_color = "#404040"

     GtkWidget::cursor_color           = "#72706E"
     GtkWidget::secondary_cursor_color = "#72706E"

     xthickness = 1
     ythickness = 1

     fg[NORMAL]        = "#d2cfcc" #Main window text
     fg[PRELIGHT]      = "#E9E9E9" #Highlighted widget text
     fg[ACTIVE]        = "#ADA59D" #Inactive widget text
     fg[SELECTED]      = "#E9E9E9"
     fg[INSENSITIVE]   = "#A18989"

     bg[NORMAL]        = "#393f3f" #Backround
     bg[PRELIGHT]      = "#3465A4" #Highlight Widget
     bg[ACTIVE]        = "#2E3232" #Selected Widget
     bg[SELECTED]      = "#3465A4" #The box words are usually in
     bg[INSENSITIVE]   = "#282B2B" #Not active buttons
     base[NORMAL]      = "#4F524F" #Text area widgets
     base[PRELIGHT]    = "#313131" #Check and radio button background
     base[ACTIVE]      = "#313636" #Unfocused Select
     base[SELECTED]    = "#2F4C6D" #Selected Text area item, and that bar over the tabs.
     base[INSENSITIVE] = "#f5f2ee" #

     text[NORMAL]      = "#EEEEEC" #Text area widget text.
     text[PRELIGHT]    = "#E9E9E9" #
     text[ACTIVE]      = "#ADA59D" #
     text[SELECTED]    = "#E9E9E9" #Selected Text area widget text.
     text[INSENSITIVE] = "#757575" #

   engine "clearlooks"
      {
       #    sunkenmenubar      = 1       # 0 = disable, 1 = enable
       #    menuitemstyle      = 1       # 0 = flat, 1 = 3d-ish (button)
       #    listviewitemstyle  = 1       # 0 = flat, 1 = 3d-ish (gradient)
       #    progressbarstyle   = 0       # 0 = candy bar, 1 = flat
     }
   }

   style "clearlooks-wide" = "clearlooks-default"
   {
     xthickness = 2
     ythickness = 2
     bg[NORMAL]   = "#414141"
     bg[PRELIGHT] = "#494949"
   }

   style "clearlooks-button" = "clearlooks-wide"
   {
     bg[NORMAL]   = "#414141"
     bg[PRELIGHT] = "#494949"
   }

   style "clearlooks-notebook" = "clearlooks-wide"
   {
     bg[NORMAL] = "#404040"
     bg[ACTIVE] = "#303030"
   }

   style "clearlooks-tasklist" = "clearlooks-default"
   {
     xthickness = 5
     ythickness = 3
   }

   style "clearlooks-menu" = "clearlooks-default"
   {
     xthickness = 2
     ythickness = 1
     bg[NORMAL] = "#404040"
   }

   style "clearlooks-menu-item" = "clearlooks-default"
   {
     xthickness = 2
     ythickness = 3
     fg[PRELIGHT]   = "#E9E9E9"
     text[PRELIGHT] = "#E9E9E9"
     base[PRELIGHT] = "#3465A4"
     base[SELECTED] = "#3465A4"
   }

   style "clearlooks-menu-itembar" = "clearlooks-default"
   {
     xthickness = 3
     ythickness = 3
   }

   style "clearlooks-tree" = "clearlooks-default"
   {
     xthickness = 2
     ythickness = 2
   }

   style "clearlooks-frame-title" = "clearlooks-default"
   {
     fg[NORMAL] = "#e2dfdc"
   }

   style "clearlooks-panel" = "clearlooks-default"
   {
     xthickness = 3
     ythickness = 3
   }

   style "clearlooks-tooltips" = "clearlooks-default"
   {
     xthickness = 4
     ythickness = 4
     bg[NORMAL] = "#3465A4"
   }

   style "clearlooks-progressbar"  = "clearlooks-default"
   {
     xthickness = 1
     ythickness = 1
      fg[PRELIGHT]         = "#e2dfdc"
      bg[NORMAL]           = "#2d1d11"
   }

   style "clearlooks-combo" = "clearlooks-default"
   {
     xthickness = 1
     ythickness = 2
     fg[NORMAL]            = "#141414"
     fg[PRELIGHT]          = "#ed7013"
     fg[ACTIVE]            = "#e2dfdc"
     bg[NORMAL]            = "#414141"
     bg[PRELIGHT]          = "#494949"
   }

   style "clearlooks-scrollbar" = "clearlooks-default"
   {
     fg[NORMAL]            = "#141414"
     fg[PRELIGHT]          = "#e2dfdc"
     fg[ACTIVE]            = "#e2dfdc"
     bg[NORMAL]            = "#414141"
     bg[PRELIGHT]          = "#494949"
   }

   style "clearlooks-spin" = "clearlooks-wide"
   {
     fg[NORMAL]            = "#141414"
     fg[PRELIGHT]          = "#e2dfdc"
     fg[ACTIVE]            = "#e2dfdc"
     bg[PRELIGHT]          = "#414141"
     bg[ACTIVE]            = "#494949"
   }

   class "GtkWidget" style "clearlooks-default"
   class "GtkRange" style "clearlooks-wide"
   class "GtkFrame" style "clearlooks-wide"
   class "GtkSpinButton" style "clearlooks-spin"
   class "GtkStatusbar" style "clearlooks-wide"
   class "GtkMenu" style "clearlooks-menu"
   class "GtkMenuItem" style "clearlooks-menu-item"
   widget_class "*MenuItem.*" style "clearlooks-menu-item"
   class "GtkEntry" style "clearlooks-wide"
   widget_class "*.tooltips.*.GtkToggleButton" style "clearlooks-tasklist"
   widget_class "*.GtkTreeView.GtkButton" style "clearlooks-tree"
   widget_class "*.GtkCTree.GtkButton" style "clearlooks-tree"
   widget_class "*.GtkList.GtkButton" style "clearlooks-tree"
   widget_class "*.GtkCList.GtkButton" style "clearlooks-tree"
   widget_class "*.GtkFrame.GtkLabel" style "clearlooks-frame-title"
   widget_class "BasePWidget.GtkEventBox.GtkTable.GtkFrame" style "clearlooks-panel"
   widget "gtk-tooltips" style "clearlooks-tooltips"
   class "GtkNotebook" style "clearlooks-notebook"
   class "GtkProgressBar" style "clearlooks-progressbar"
   widget_class "*.GtkComboBox.GtkButton" style "clearlooks-combo"
   widget_class "*.GtkCombo.GtkButton" style "clearlooks-combo"
   class "GtkButton" style "clearlooks-button"
   class "GtkScrollbar" style "clearlooks-scrollbar"
   ```

Comment: It is already enabled... You can see that on screenshot. My settings.init looks just like that as well.

Comment: @MislavBlažević, I think you should find an Adweita theme for Firefox, or create a userChrome.css file for it on yourself. Firefox is not a GTK app, it’s just made compatible with it.

Comment: Editing ~/.config/gtk-2.0/settings.ini has no effect. gtkrc-dark file does not exist.

Comment: @MislavBlažević  https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=116652&p=2 .The issue is gtk2 does not have adwaita-dark .You will have Download it separately .see the above thread

Comment: @Stormvirux, you wrote: "you will also have to Edit ~/.config/gtk-2.0/settings.ini". Are you sure that gtk-2.0 uses settings.ini? I thought it was only gtk-3.0 that does so.

Comment: @MislavBlažević Is this whay you had in your mind?? http://img833.imageshack.us/img833/6711/x3kg.png.Or do you even want the pages to be dark?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I had in mind.

Comment: @MislavBlažević ok That reqires editing your gtkrc file in /usr/share/themes/Adwita<themename>/gtk-2.0.I will edit the answer and post my gtkrc with steps how I implemented it

Comment: @Stormvirux
One more thing. All text in comb-boxes and forms like this is unreadable because it is light gray on white. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: @Stormvirux nevermind last comment! I figured it out myself. Thanks for this theme, I LOVE IT!!

Comment: Oof, I went ahead and did this. It made Firefox sort of work in Ubuntu 3.10, but the titlebar was still white and the theme looked pretty bad in general and inconsistent with Adwaita. Bummer this won't get fixed for a long time.

Comment: http://img833.imageshack.us/img833/6711/x3kg.png

Comment: Sorry for the necro comment here. I found this Q/A to be helpful in this problem in Ubuntu Gnome 14.04, however I didn't use the code provided by Stromvirux (I tried it, but it just gave an old Firefox 4.0 look to it, rather than a dark adwita). I instead used the default `gtkrc` and just replaced the line with the `gtk-color-scheme` with the following: 
`gtk-color-scheme        = "base_color:#4F524F\nfg_color:#eeeeec\ntooltip_fg_color:#eeeeee\nselected_bg_color:#3465a4\nselected_fg_color:#eeeeec\ntext_color:#EEEEEC\nbg_color:#363B3B\ninsensitive_bg_color:#8c8984\ntooltip_bg_color:#000000"`

Comment: Source for the code in my comment (with a slight modification to include `insensitive_bg_color`) is here: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=998162#p998162

Comment: Recent version of firefox uses GTK3.

Answer (score 2):

On newer Firefox versions (67) GTK3 dark theme support is still rubbish.
(Form widgets often render with wrong colors.)  Here's a band-aid fix:

```
Goto: about:config 
Add String entry: widget.content.gtk-theme-override
Set value to: Adwaita:light
Goto Customizations: choose Dark theme
```

Comment: Can you describe the fourth step "Goto Customizations: choose Dark theme" a bit more? It's not clear on my end what that is about. Otherwise thanks for this suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

on Debian bullseye I did the following:

1. install Tweaks
2. open Tweaks > Appearance > Themes: Applications "Adwaita-dark"
3. open Firefox > Settings

3.1. > Language and Appearance: Website appearance "System theme"

3.2 > Colors > Manage Colors

3.2.1 > tick "Use system colors"

3.2.2 > Override the colors specified by the page with your selections above: Always