# Hide title bar in Gnome 3.12

Tags: gnome, 14.04

I have Ubuntu 14.04 and Gnome 3.12 (using a dark theme) and in some applications I have now a big, white title bar.

How can I remove title bar of an application? In gnome 3.10 I used gnome-shell-extension [pixel saver](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/723/pixel-saver/) but now this extensions is outdated.

[image]

Comment: If you want to remove title bars for maximized windows, you can use [the second method](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/05/how-to-remove-maximized-windows.html#more)
. However, it will not be removed for windows with Client Side Decorations.

Answer (score 4):

I solved this by using [Maximus](https://bitbucket.org/mathematicalcoffee/maximus-gnome-shell-extension).

For newer versions of gnome (> 3.8) you may need to [edit metadata.json to match this pull request](https://bitbucket.org/mathematicalcoffee/maximus-gnome-shell-extension/pull-request/4/update-metadata-for-gnome-shell-310-and/diff) and manually install the extension. Instructions lifted from maximus homepage with a few edits:

```
hg clone ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/mathematicalcoffee/maximus-gnome-shell-extension
hg up gnome3.4 # or `stable` if on GNOME 3.2
cd maximus-gnome-shell-extension
# NOW OPEN AND EDIT THE OUTDATED metadata.json FILE. See link above.
make # <-- VERY IMPORTANT
cp -r maximus@mathematical.coffee.gmail.com ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
# enable maximus if you haven't already:
gnome-shell-extension-tool -e maximus@mathematical.coffee.gmail.com
Restart gnome-shell.
```

Comment: There also is [this extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/844/maximus-two/), which apparently will work with 3.12.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to the wonderful world of Gnome 3.12's forced client side decorations. CSD are hardcoded in GTK 3.12, the only way to get rid of them is to downgrade GTK to V 3.10.

Comment: Hmmm... well I have some themes installed that at least re-color the title bar, but I can't seem to get that code working in Adwaita or Adwaita-borderless to be more precise. Any Ideas? I just want to make the title bar solid black.

Comment: Actually, I'm running 3.10 I think: ii  libgtk-3-0:amd64       3.10.8-0ubuntu1  amd64            GTK+ graphical user interface library
ii  libgtk2.0-0:amd64      2.24.23-0ubuntu1 amd64            GTK+ graphical user interface library

Answer (score 2):

Gnome Shell Extension `Pixel Saver` just works.

https://github.com/deadalnix/pixel-saver

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `Tweak Tool` and change the Window Theme from there.

Answer (score 1):

Like alb3rtano0012 suggested, you should download [Tweak Tool](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/saucy/gnome-tweak-tool/) aka. 'Advanced Settings' [Tweak advanced GNOME 3 settings], that enables you to choose a different `window theme`, matching your overall dark GTK+theme.

Since it is not included yet in the 14.04 repos you can install it like this:

1. Open a terminal window.
2. Type in the following command then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

> sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool gnome-tweak-tool

<sub>Source: [Install tweak tools in Ubuntu 14.04](http://www.itworld.com/software/415242/install-tweak-tools-ubuntu-1404)  |  Guide 01</sub>

[image]

> GNOME Tweak Tool allows the adjustment of several advanced GNOME options that can't be configured in gnome-control-center. This includes things like:

- fonts used in user interface elements and titlebar
- font hinting and aliasing
- alternative user interface themes
- changes in window management behaviour
- behaviour on laptop lid close
- file manager desktop icons
- icons in menus and buttons

Comment: I don't think changing the window theme would work. I haven't installed custom themes but it doesn't work with the default ones that come pre-installed. Can you provide a working example for how to actually make it work.

Comment: How to you apply/change the default themes and what exactly doesn't work? Some more information would be helpful. You can always edit your question and add more information. Also have you already tried my suggestion in the answer and that didn't work as well?!

Comment: Did it actually work for you? You haven't provided a screenshot showing where the Title bar is hidden. Your answer is not an answer, just a guidance which might work in your belief. BTW, I am not the OP of the question.

Comment: Tweak Tool only changes gtk3 settings, but some apps, e.g. Firefox, Sublime Text 3, run on gtk2. Options exist, though I'm still searching for something that works for 3.12. For some info, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/337018/firefox-not-affected-by-gtk-theme , https://plus.google.com/+RoiMMrNucky/posts/KsybAs8Htgc , https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=151846

Comment: Changing your window theme as suggested in Tweak Tool will work although it will appear not to work until you restart GNOME. Alt+F2 to open the run prompt then type just "r" and press enter. This will restart GNOME and thus activate the CSD of that theme. Numix is a great example of this working.

Comment: @MichaelTunnell On my end, Numix only darkens the title bar. It does not remove it.

Comment: @MattY correct, my point is that you have to restart GNOME to see the affect but if you haven't applied the affect it won't work. Numix does not provide this affect as it is not meant to. - http://www.webupd8.org/2011/05/how-to-remove-maximized-windows.html use Method #2 and it will work. - I added this as a solution if you want to upvote it :) http://askubuntu.com/a/520155/72652

Comment: @MichaelTunnell I solved the problem on my end and completely forgot about this thread. Looks like you found a similar solution to mine. Personally, I think it's a little easier to edit the json file from the repo... hopefully the maintainer of maximus merges the pull request soon.

Answer (score 1):

If you read this tutorial from WebUpd8 you will be able to manually make these changes. - http://www.webupd8.org/2011/05/how-to-remove-maximized-windows.html

Follow the steps for Method #2.

Note- Method #1 is no longer maintained so it is not relevant anymore but Method #2 does still work.

This is if you want to remove the titlebar completely, if you want to blend the titlebar with the theme then @v2r's solution is more applicable.