# How can I toggle between dark mode and light mode on the command line?

Tags: gnome

What is a command line command to toggle between the GNOME desktop dark mode and light mode?

Answer (score 7):

(Tested on Ubuntu 22.04. This works in Ubuntu's customized Gnome session and also in the vanilla Gnome session from the `vanilla-gnome-desktop` package.)

You can use the `gsettings` command in a terminal to change the value of the `org.gnome.desktop.interface color-scheme` setting to either `prefer-dark` or `prefer-light`:

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface color-scheme prefer-dark
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface color-scheme prefer-light
```

For legacy apps (for example: GNOME Terminal) you also need to set the `org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme` setting to either `'Adwaita-dark'` or `'Adwaita'`:

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme 'Adwaita-dark'
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme 'Adwaita'
```

Here's a shell script that will toggle between light mode and dark mode:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
set -euo

if test "$(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface color-scheme)" = "'prefer-light'"; then
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface color-scheme prefer-dark
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme 'Adwaita-dark'
else
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface color-scheme prefer-light
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme 'Adwaita'
fi
```

You can create a custom keyboard shortcut for the script in the **Settings** app (under **Keyboard** → **View and Customize Shortcuts** → **Custom Shortcuts**):

[image: Creating a custom keyboard shortcut for the script]

(In the screenshot I've saved the script at `~/.gsettings/toggle-light-dark-mode.sh` and made it executable by running: `chmod u+x ~/.gsettings/toggle-light-dark-mode.sh`.)

Comment: Thanks @Sean I might try this. I wondered, can you explain a bit what apps/software/windows will be affected by toggling?

Comment: I mean, will it affect [websites in firefox](https://askubuntu.com/q/337018/1688470)

Comment: Yes if you use the Dark Reader extension and set it up to follow the system preference (it has "automation options")