# Can I give gedit (v 41.0) "preferred" themes to select when it responds to a change in Ubuntu's (v 22.04 LTS) dark/light mode?

Tags: gnome, themes, 22.04, gedit

### Context:

When I select "Dark" or "Light" in Ubuntu's Settings > Appearance > Style, gedit detects this change and switches its internal them to Yaru Dark or Yaru Light appropriately. I really like this feature! But I would prefer that gedit use the Builder and Builder Dark themes (which interact better with markdown syntax highlighting for my purposes) instead of Yaru.

### Question:

Is it possible to configure gedit such that, when it gets the message from Ubuntu/GNOME to switch to a dark or light style, it will choose a specific theme for either instead of the default Yaru variant?

### Related:

I found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1234819/1614548) on using `gsettings` to switch GNOME's theme interesting, as I'd love to be able to toggle dark/light mode from within gedit via an external tool hotkey. I noticed that switching the desktop theme this way does *not* trigger gedit to switch its internal theme, nor does it change whether Dark or Light is selected in Settings > Appearance > Style.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround, adapted from [this answer on command line dark/light toggling](https://askubuntu.com/a/1406617/1614548). I now just run this script, via a custom keyboard shortcut, in order to switch between dark and light modes.

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
set -euo

if test "$(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface color-scheme)" = "'prefer-light'"; then
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface color-scheme prefer-dark
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme 'Yaru-dark'
  sleep 1
  gsettings set org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor scheme 'builder-dark'
else
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface color-scheme prefer-light
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme 'Yaru'
  sleep 1
  gsettings set org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor scheme 'builder'
fi
```

The `sleep 1` is needed because, only when the Settings application is open, Ubuntu/GNOME will animate the switch between GTK themes – so whatever handler gedit has to catch that theme change will execute after a slight delay.